# Angular response data not showing in html page

Tags: angular

Data is coming from API and I see the console log but html page not showing!

component.ts

```
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {
  appSetting: AppSetting[] = [];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.AppSetting().then((result: AppSetting[]) => {
      this.appSetting = result;
    });
    console.log(this.appSetting);
  }

  async AppSetting() {
    return await this.http
      .get<AppSetting[]>(environment.apiUrl + '/AppSetting/GetsPublich')
      .toPromise();
  }
}
```

component.html

```html
<ul *ngFor="let item of appSetting">
  <li>{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Looks good to me (except, you probably want to add `ngFor` to the `li` element instead of `ul`). Have you checked if your template is displayed at all (by adding some static content)?

Comment: it should work actually try to clear your browser caches

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `| async` in the *ngFor while using the async function.

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of appSetting | async">
  <li>{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: async for observable with behaviorsubject objects , so it will not work bro.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is because of that you are trying to display data before the data is fetched by the `async` function.
May be you can solve this problem easily by not initializing the array; so change this:

```
appSetting: AppSetting[] = [];
```

to

```
appSetting: AppSetting[];
```

And surround the `<ul>` with the `<div *ngIf="appSetting">...</div>` like this below:

```
<div *ngIf="appSetting">
  <ul *ngFor="let item of appSetting">
    <li>{{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but didn't work